# Separating a single input into two arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

If i have a function splitter("w8h76f") and want it to return me 'whf, 876'

```
>splitter("w8h76f")
> 'whf, 876'
```

I have defined the function below:

```
> def splitter(string)
> s = string
>print (s[0::2])
>print (s[1::2])
```

but the problem is what if the input is rearranged like "wh6f78" it'll give me the wrong answer.How can i improve my function that it splits the the input into two different arguments

Answer (score 1):

```
"".join(c for c in s if c.isalpha())
"".join(c for c in s if c.isdigit())
```

Comment: what did you do? I don't understand.

Comment: The first generator filters only the alphabetic characters and joins them with the empty string between them. The second one does the same for the digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
def splt(st):
    import re
    return ''.join(re.findall('[0-9]', st)), \
           ''.join(re.findall('[A-Za-z]', st))

>>>splt("w8h76f")
('876', 'whf')
```